# JavaScript: Использование приватных методов в JavaScript + VSCode + babel-eslint

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, babel, eslint

Проблема заключается в том, что линтер babel-eslint ругается на приватные методы в классах: `Parsing error: This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'classPrivateMethods'`.

Пробовал обновить babel-eslint до 11.0.0-beta.2, а также ставить плагины `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods` и `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`, естественно не забывая добавить их в файле `.babelrc.json`.

Comment: [How do I enable ESLint classPrivateMethods parser plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53675785/2881286)

Comment: `babel-eslint` давно умер, обновитесь до `@babel/eslint-parser`

Comment: @Grundy, ни один из ответов не решил проблему

Comment: @vp_arth, теперь он ругается на `import odbc from '../../node_modules/odbc'` следующим образом: `Parsing error: No Babel config file detected for <путь к моему js-файлу>. Either disable config file checking with requireConfigFile: false, or configure Babel so that it can find the config files.`.
Первый раз в жизни решил попробовать писать на JS, в частности на NodeJS, и вся эта мелкая возня с пакетами убивает

Comment: https://github.com/standard/vscode-standardjs/issues/100#issuecomment-686435590

Comment: @vp_arth, я создал файл .babel.config.js в корневой папке, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: К слову, он такую же ошибку пишет и в первой строке файла babel.config.js